# How to specify a storage pool for images?

Tags: lxc, lxd

Let's say I have two storage pools configured. On the first one I want to deploy Ubuntu-based containers, and on the other, for example, Debian-based containers.

1. How to specify a pool when copying an image from remote servers such as `images:` or `ubuntu:`?
2. Is it possible to specify a pool instead of `local:` in the `image copy` command?
3. What is `local:` and how does LXD know where to install the image if there are multiple pools on the system?
4. If I have multiple pools with different drivers, will LXD still only store images on one specific volume on one specific pool?

I know that using this command - `lxc config set storage.images_volume POOLNAME/VOLUMENAME` - you can specify a specific location to save images. But what if I want to save a specific image to a specific pool? Is this possible?

Or do I fundamentally misunderstand what LXD does with images? If I understand correctly, the image will be saved even if you create a container with one command `lxc init|launch <remote>:<image> <instance>`. With this command I can specify a profile with a disk device that uses a different pool. However, where will the image be saved - in the pool where I install the container or in another location? How to control this process? What if I want to install the image myself and configure containers manually?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And stick to one question instead of asking multiple questions.